# AutoMapper mapping exception on model and DTO

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, automapper

I've got a mapping for an Entity Framework domain model class and its DTO class.

**Model:**

```
public class UserAccount : BaseEntity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor.
    /// </summary>
    public UserAccount() => Users = new HashSet<User>();

    #region Public Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// The email address of this user account.
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(255)]    
    public string Email { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The password of this user account.
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(500)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The verified status of this user account.
    /// </summary>
    public bool Verified { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The associated list of <see cref="User"/> for this user account.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Helpers

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string str = base.ToString();
        str +=
        $"Email: {Email}{Environment.NewLine}" +
        $"Password: {Password}{Environment.NewLine}" +
        $"Verified: {Verified}";
        return str;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**DTO:**

```
public class UserAccountDto
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The email address of this user account.
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(255)]    
    public string Email { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The password of this user account.
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(500)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

I've mapped and registered them in the Global.asax, here's the mapping code:

```
// Domain.
CreateMap<UserAccount, UserAccountDto>();

// DTO.
CreateMap<UserAccountDto, UserAccount>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForMember(dest => dest.EntityCreated, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForMember(dest => dest.EntityActive, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForMember(dest => dest.EntityVersion, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Verified, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Users, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

I'm attempting to map the DTO to the domain so I can save the domain to my database, using the following code:

```
UserAccount userAccount = Mapper.Map<UserAccount>(userAccountDto);
```

However I get this error:

```
AutoMapper created this type map for you, but your types cannot be mapped using the current configuration.
UserAccountDto -> UserAccount (Destination member list)
OysterCard.Models.Dto.UserAccount.UserAccountDto -> OysterCard.Models.Security.UserAccount (Destination member list)

Unmapped properties:
Verified
Users
Id
EntityCreated
EntityActive
EntityVersion
```

What am I doing wrong here? I've mapped the above properties so I'm not sure where it's going wrong. I'm quite new to AutoMapper so I could be going obviously wrong somewhere but I'm not sure where exactly.

If someone could help me resolve my issue I would be very grateful.

Thank you.

Comment: Read the message again, if AM created that map for you, then clearly your map is not used. The configuration part is wrong.

Comment: What is wrong about it? It looks like I've mapped what it's said I've not, so what could it be?

Comment: No, that's _exactly_ what happened :) You didn't configure AM correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realised what went wrong.

My configuration was in a different project which also had AutoMapper installed via Nuget, because of this, when I initialised my mappings, it was being mapped agaisnt the other instance of AutoMapper and not the one I was using within the Controller in my ASP.NET project.

Should've caught onto this earlier, schoolboy error 101!